# Error message pop up on C# Angular JS Web page

Tags: angularjs

Whenever the Web page loads, this pops up. Clicking okay loads the data to the dashboard.

[image]

This pops up looks like not throwing an error, it displays the entire function.

Please help to suppress this notification

Comment: Post your code and any errors as *text* in the question itself. It's impossible to say what that partial screenshot shows. Is that an error page? Your own code that opened up a window or called `alert` ? Whatever it is, it's in the application's Angular code. This has nothing to do with C#. We can't guess what the code is doing

Comment: As for `suppress this notification` you don't cover up bugs, you fix them. Covering them up doesn't mean the application will run, it means you won't know when it crashes